# Tern doesn't work properly with eclipse

Tags: angularjs, node.js, eclipse, tern

Recently I installed the AngularJS Eclipse plugin ([Link](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse)).

I use Eclipse Luna. I followed the [Getting Started](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started) section and made all described steps.

But the tern seems to work not properly.

The Tern cannot find the names of my controllers, modules, cannot navigate to it.

[image]

It seams NodeJS (which I installed in C - PrgrammFiles) works properly,
but on the console I get following error:

[image]

I also get an empty Angular Explorer view

[image]

I googled but couldn't find any solution.

Please help me.

Comment: Sorry for the links, I dont have anough reputaton to post a styled question.

Comment: Please create an issue at https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/issues and share your project (create a github project for that)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have inserted your images for you; however, two of the images only contain text. It  would be better if you pasted that text into  the question and not and image of the text! This can be done using the [edit] button. This will make it easier for people to understand your question and give you a timely answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT from the following [site](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) did the trick for me. Now the AngularJS Eclipse plugin work as expected.

Go in Eclipse to Help - Install new software.. - and paste the link as described in the following section:

**Update site for 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT is available at http://oss.opensagres.fr/angularjs-eclipse/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/**